# How to grab specific JSON entry using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, modal-dialog

Here's a picture of the current output:
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKBcJ.png)

I'm trying to have it show the active title when you click download, and not every entry.
I'm also trying to have it show the download file(s) name instead of static text, or the URL.

The JS code that loads the titles is:

```
(function($){
    var titledbApp = angular.module('dsshop', ['angular-loading-bar'])
                            .config(['cfpLoadingBarProvider', function(cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
                              cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeSpinner = false;
                              cfpLoadingBarProvider.parentSelector = '#loading-bar-container';
                            }]);

    titledbApp.controller('TitleListController', function TitleListController($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('https://nitrobrew.github.io/BrewShopNitro/list0.json').then(function(response){
            $scope.titles = response.data.sort(function(a, b){
              if(a.name.toUpperCase() < b.name.toUpperCase()) return -1;
              if(a.name.toUpperCase() > b.name.toUpperCase()) return 1;
              return 0;
            });
        });
    });

    //Filesize filter, credit to https://gist.github.com/yrezgui/5653591
    titledbApp.filter( 'filesize', function () {
        var units = [
            'bytes',
            'KB',
            'MB',
            'GB',
            'TB',
            'PB'
        ];

        return function( bytes, precision ) {
            if ( isNaN( parseFloat( bytes )) || ! isFinite( bytes ) ) {
              return '?';
            }

            var unit = 0;

            while ( bytes >= 1024 ) {
              bytes /= 1024;
              unit ++;
            }

            return bytes.toFixed( + precision ) + ' ' + units[ unit ];
        };
    });
})();
```

The HTML code that loads the modal box (bootstrap modal) is:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="downloadModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="downloadModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                        aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" ng-repeat="title in titles">
                    <center>{{title.name}} download menu</center>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <a ng-href="{{title.files[0].url}}" title="{{title.files[0].url}}"
                    ng-repeat="title in titles">File 1</a>
                <br>
                <a href="{{title.files[1]}}">{{title.files[1]}}</a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-blue" data-dismiss="modal"
                    data-toggle="tooltip">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I want it to show only the related info to the download that is clicked on, am I allowed to post site link/source code to show?

https://nitrobrew.github.io/BrewShopNitro/

Comment: you still there?